# Programmatically localize a Text property in a WP8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8

As the title says, I'm trying to set (in the code) the Text property of a TextBlock to the right localized string in a Windows Phone 8 app.

I've tried this:
(VB)

```
statusValueTxt.Text = "{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.statusValueTxt_Charging,Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
```

as I would use this code in the XAML, but it doesn't seem to work in the code.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has to be a resource class (probably AppResources), that has multiple properties according to the localized strings you have in your app. Usage is then following:

```
yourTextBox.Text = AppResources.SomeResource;
```